# What exactly does it mean for a function to be on $(X,d)$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am attempting to do an exercise, but I am not sure what something means in the exercise itself (something I may have missed in my maths education previously I suppose). Here is the exercise:

Exercise: If $(X,d)$ is a bounded metric space **(I know what this means)** show that the product of two Lipschitz continuous real valued function on $(X,d)$ is again Lipschitz continuous.

Now, what exactly does it mean for a function to be **on** $(X,d)$? Does it mean its domain and codomain is $(X,d)$?

Also, there is a hint at the end of the exercise:

Hint: Show that a real-valued Lipschitz function on a bounded metric space must be bounded.

Since the confusion regarding the first part of my question, I'm not sure what's the codomain of it, and I think that the codomain may be unbounded. But this is probably not true.

If you could clarify what the statement means in my question above I would be grateful.

Comment: the part where is says it's on $(X,d)$ means the domain is $(X,d)$ and the part where it says it's real valued means the codomain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: This simply means a function whose domain is $X$ and which is Lipschitz with respect to the metric $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is a Lipschitz continuous real-valued function **on** $(X,d)$ means that:

- $f:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$: its domain is $X$ because its defined on $(X,d)$, its codomain is $\mathbb R$ because is real-valued.
- Lipschitz continuity: $\exists L\geq0\ \mid\ \|f(x)-f(y)\|<L \cdot d(x,y) \ \forall x,y\in X$. i.e. is lipschitz-continuous respect the distance $d$ in the domain $X$ and the euclidean distance in the codomain $\mathbb R$.

Comment: so, what is $\|x-y\|$ when $(X,d)$ is only a metric space?

Comment: sorry, I'ts a mistake. It is $\|f(x)-f(y)\|$

Comment: and $\|\cdot\|$ denote the euclidean norm in $\mathbb R$